# How to exclude Sitecore user roles from workflow?

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7

In a Sitecore project workflows are installed on several templates. I want to exclude some user roles from the workflow. Everyone who creates an item based on a workflow must follow the workflow now.

I want for example that users with a role Content Manager are excluded from workflow and a Content Editor not.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks a lot,
Jordy

Comment: So you want ContentEditor1 to have to go through a workflow with all the items which are in that workflow, and ContentManager1 not? I don't think it's possible. You should be able however to create a new command `ImmediatePublish` and assign access rights for `Content Manager` role only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example for ddysart's answer.

Here is an example.

Let's say you have 2 roles -
1. Publisher - has to go through the entire workflow
2. Super user - can go through the entire workflow or just publish from any workflow state

Let's say you have a workflow with 3 states and their actions -

1. Draft state - initial state of an item. It has the following actions -

   - Submit for Approval - pushes item to Awaiting Approval state
   - Approve and Publish - pushes item to Approved state and bypasses all the workflow states and actions in the states between Draft and Approved states.
2. Awaiting Approval state - next state of an item. It has the following action -

   - Approve and Publish - pushes item to Approved state
3. Approved state - final state of an item, which also automatically publishes it.

   - Auto-Publish - automatically publishes an item.

For Publishers, let the users have access to all states and actions, except for Approve and Publish in the Draft state. Hide the Approve and Publish button by denying Read access write on that item for the Publisher role.

For Super Users, let the users have acces to all states and actions, including Approve and Publish in the draft state. This way the Super User can publish without having to go through each step.

Answer (score 2):

The only users completely excluded from workflow are admins, which I wouldn't suggest since that role has a lot more privileges you don't want "normal" users to have.

Could you add a set of actions only the Content Editor role has access to? Those roles will still have to push items through workflow, but you could allow them bypass all of the main steps.

Comment: Those roles will still have to push items through workflow, but you could allow them bypass all of the main steps. Sounds good! How?